# What is the difference between FS0 and BLK0 in UEFI shell mappings?

Tags: shell, uefi

I think FS stands for filesystem, but I don't know what BLK stands for. Not only that, but what are the meanings behind the pci hierarchy parameters. i.e. When I see HD(1,MBR,0x0003B) what does "1","MBR", and what looks to be an address, stand for?

Here's the mapping table I'm looking at in UEFI shell:

```
Mapping table
  FS0: Alias(s):HD21a0e0b:;BLK1:
      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1D,0x0)/USB(0x0,0x0)/USB(0x4,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x0003B)
  FS1: Alias(s):HD23a0a1:;BLK4:
      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1F,0x2)/Sata(0x0,0x0,0x0)/HD(1,MBR,0x00000000,0x3F)
 BLK3: Alias(s):
      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1F,0x2)/Sata(0x0,0x0,0x0)
 BLK0: Alias(s):
      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1D,0x0)/USB(0x0,0x0)/USB(0x4,0x0)
 BLK2: Alias(s):
      PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1D,0x0)/USB(0x0,0x0)/USB(0x4,0x0)/HD(2,MBR,0x0003B)
```

I'm guessing BLK's are available ports and FS's are physical things that are plugged into those ports. It looks like once somethign is plugged into a BLK, it becomes an FS, but still retains its BLK value. i.g. FS0=BLK1

Comment: what was the uefi shell command you were using, `map` with what flags?

Comment: just `map`, no flags.

Comment: sorry couldn't find more about it. Especially about the hex numbers `0x...` :(. See my last edit!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Important_UEFI_Shell_Commands):

- `fsX` means `filesystem`
- `blkX` means `block device` or `data storage device`

`MBR` should mean `Master Boot Record`

`HD` should mean `Hard Drive`

`1` might mean `Primary`, `2` `Secondary Partition`

That hex number after MBR could be the device signature or disk identifier. Or maybe an offset of that device to important information.

Links that might help further:

- [RHEL 5 Installation Guide EFI Shell Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-ia64-intro-efi-shell.html)
- [Red Hat 7.1 Itanium EFI Shell Guide](http://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/7.1/en/doc/RH-DOCS/rhl-ig-itanium-en-7.1/efi-shell.html)
- [HP Knowledge Base: "UEFI Shell 'fs' devices gone after restore from image backup"](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware/UEFI-Shell-fs-devices-gone-after-restore-from-image-backup/td-p/5582017)
- [OpenVMS: Firmware upgrades from a USB stick (on UEFI)](http://www.hgenhart.ch/index.php/edv/openvms/354-integrity)
- [SourceForge EFI Shell Development Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/efi-shell/files/documents/)